# How to check if a Keyword exists in an Access Query

Tags: ms-access, vba

My question is quite simple but my access database have multiple queries and I want to write an automate process to check if certain keyword exists in any of the queries. This automate process can either be a query or a VBA. Can someone please give me an idea where to start?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this for a completely different purpose - but it may give you a place to start.  It lookps through all queries, looking for a specific string and replacing it with a different one.

```
Function MassChange(F_string, T_string)
Dim DB As Database
Dim QD As QueryDef
Dim S As String

Set DB = CurrentDb
For Each QD In DB.QueryDefs
    S = QD.SQL
    If InStr(S, F_string) > 0 Then
        S = Replace(S, F_string, T_string)
        QD.SQL = S
    End If
Next QD
MsgBox ("done")

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

@vivi Use @Don-George's answer, but if you just want the query's name(s), replace the middle part:

```
If InStr(S, F_string) > 0 Then
    Debug.Print QD.Name
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! It's very helpful!